# Unknown server tag 'SharePoint:FlightedContent'

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page

I copied a Master Page from a SharePoint Online site and started working with it on a SharePoint 2013 VM.  When trying to load a page on the VM that uses this Master Page I get this error:

> Unknown server tag 'SharePoint:FlightedContent'.

When looking up on [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.aspx) the `FlightedContent` is currently listed, but greyed out.

Eventually I will re-deploy this Master Page back to the SharePoint Online environment but am wondering if there is a way to get around this error while working on the VM?

Comment: SharePoint Online is more up-to-date then available SharePoint versions for the on-premise. It's possible that this control only exists in SPO.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know if I can substitute it for another control?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure if that /is/ the answer. I don't know which control that is.

Comment: Already solved in another issue : [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144079/unknown-server-tag-webpartpageswebpartzone)