# Unknown server tag "WebPartPages:WebPartZone"

Tags: page-layout, custom, wiki-pages

I try to add a webpart zone to a page layout in SharePoint Online.

I added this code:

```
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Content1" runat="Server">-->
    <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="true" ID="WebPartZone2" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Title="Bottom" Orientation="Vertical">-->
        <!--MS: <ZoneTemplate>-->
            <!--MS:<WebPartPages:ClientWebPart runat="server"
                FeatureId="e8a884cf-f7d3-44ab-be09-5e5595171495"
                ProductWebId="32d215ce-7a60-4812-b847-ef52de360cab"
                WebPartName="Name"
                Title="Project"
                Description="WebPart Description"
                WebPart="true">-->
            <!--ME:</WebPartPages:ClientWebPart>-->
        <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
    <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
<!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

If I open the modified page I get this error: "Unknown server tag 'WebPartPages:WebPartZone".

On the top of my file I have this reference but it does not work:

```
<!--SPM:<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
```

Comment: It seems you are using a snippet for the assembly for the 2010 version of SharePoint, replace 14.0 with 15.0

Comment: Changed the version number in my reference, but I get the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same issue occurred at my end when I placed the assembly reference in the page directives (top of the page layout). Namespace was as below:

```
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
```

So I simply added this namespace before the webpart zone and removed from top of the page. This looks weird but it worked.

```
<!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <div xmlns:ie="ie">
        <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="x3156ba02c8c5468e88797eb78c36089f" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" Orientation="Vertical">-->
           <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
               <!-- Your Custom Client WebPart Code Goes Here -->
           <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
        <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
    </div>
<!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is really weird and I have no idea why, but it works! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have all the following tags added at the top of your page layout.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

Above first webpart zone added in your pagelayout `<WebPartPages:WebPartZone` 
make sure you have `<WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spproxywebpartmanager1"></WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>`
added

Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I added the references to the top of the page layout and added the <WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>-tag but now I get this error message: "Unknown server tag 'WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager'".

Comment: Can you share the code of your entire page layout? and also mention which version of sharepoint are you using.

Comment: I am using SharePoint Online. Sorry, but it's a customized page from a customer and unfortunately I am not allowed to share the code.